# How can I control Spring RequestBody converting JSON request body to object?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Spring @RequestBody annotation automatically converts JSON request body to Object. The converting process seems a black box for us. However, I need to control the converting process to fail my expected invalid input.

Look at the code below. The JSON request body contains an "id" String with an uppercase letter. When Spring automatically converts it to a UUID object, it will be successful.

```
// the controller
public class IndexController {
    ...
    public ResponseEntity<Void> postIndexes(@ApiParam(value = INDEXES_DESC, required = true) @Valid @RequestBody @Size(min = 1, max = 2000) List<Index> indexes) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

// the Index class
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Index implements Serializable {
    @ApiModelProperty(value = ID_DESC, example = SINGLE_ID)
    @NotNull
    private UUID                id;
    ...
}

// the input JSON request body
[
    {
        ...
        "id": "40336c2b-591a-4472-a270-111111A46339",
        ...
    }
]
```

However, I want this kind of input with uppercase letters fails. Not sure what does the @RequestBody annotation magically do. Looks it used UUID.fromString() to convert the String input to UUID Object. But I want to have some control on the converting process to fail it.

Comment: You can use `ObjectMapper` for the conversion

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya The problem is the ObjectMapper is out of my control. It is something within the black box in Spring. Could you provide an example how to control it in spring?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for property editors also.